# Can JavaScript be used to load another page's metadata content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

On my website all the pages have an author in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="Author" content="Mark Brown" />
```

I want to create a page of links and next to each call that page's Author metadata content value with jQuery.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
.load( '{URLHERE}' + $('meta[name=Author]').attr('content') )
```

Sorry I'm a JS Newbie. I seems that `.load()` only gets content inside the `body` tag? Is that right? Any ideas how I'd do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you were asking your question, there was a box to the right of the editing area labelled **How to Format**. Worth a read, as the result of not marking thing sup correctly part of your question was originally invisible. :-) Also worth taking a look at the **[?]** link above the editing area. There's also a preview area under the editing area so you can see how things are going to look.

Comment: The syntax you might have been looking for is `.load("URL selector")` but this will load the whole `meta` tag into the destination. You could use the `complete` `callback` to make additional adjustments as I indicated in my solution. Performance wont be great when pulling an entire page though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `load` event in two stages:

```
$("#your-target").load("{URLHERE} meta[name='Author']", function(response, status, xhr){
    var $meta = $("meta", this);

    $(this).text($meta.attr("content"));

    $meta.remove();
});
```

This will first load the `meta` tag into your destination and by using the `complete` `callback`, you can get the value of the Author attribute.

Comment: Both answers were great! This one was useful in getting the value back onto the page. Thanks again guys!

Comment: @JasonB hey, I edited the post to remove the `meta` tag from the DOM after you use it and also cleaned up the selector to the preferred method.

Answer (score 3):

`.load` loads the content into the destination element, which you seem not to want. You want to use `.get`

```
$.get(url, function() {
    var author = $('meta[name=Author]').attr('content');
    // do what you need with author
})
```

Edit: after being pointed out that this code fetches data from the current page and not the desired one, I tried something like this:

```
$.get(url, function(result) {
    var author = $(result).find('meta[name=Author]').attr('content');
});
```

but it turns out that, even though result has a meta tag, the find doesn't return anything. Trying to find a div `$(result).find('div')` works fine though. A possibility is appending the result to a dom element and querying:

```
$.get(url, function(result) {
    var dom = $('<div></div>').html(result);
    var author = dom.find('meta[name=Author]').attr('content');
});
```

It works but it's deadly slow. I would recommend a server side approach to retrieve these data. A client side solution would make X requests if you have X links, that's probably a waste.

Comment: `var author = $('meta[name=Author]').attr('content');` will get the `content` attribute of the selected element on the current page unless I missed something.

Comment: true, I was testing on the same page and it wasn't evident, trying to fix it.

Comment: Decent updated solution! Definitely a performance penalty in both of our solutions and going server side may be a better approach. Removed the downvote. Cheers

Comment: how can the `author` variable be kept without the page reloading as blank?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by page reloading as blank. `author` only exists within the callback function, if you want to use the value somewhere else you'd possibly assign it to another element in an outer scope.

Comment: Using the code `$.get(url, function(result) {
          var dom = $('<div ></div>').html(result);
          var Author = dom.find("meta[name='Author']").attr("content");
          
          // test value returned
          console.log('Author = ' + Author);
          alert(Author);
      });` Once the alert box has been dismissed the page clears to a blank html document. I assume it's caused by `$('<div></div>')`? But without that the author variable is undefined.

Comment: `$('<div></div>')` only creates an element but doesn't attach it to the dom, so it doesn't interfere with current page. Although I tested it only on the console, I'm pretty sure it doesn't cause this side-effect. Could it be that your code runs something else after it?

Answer (score 0):

you are right, from the docs:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as html,
>   title, or head elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

You could create a small serverside script which fetches the document and does the html parsing for you and returns the metadata accordingly. You can then call this script via ajax.